# Angular Location of inherited parent HTML template

Tags: angular, inheritance, angular2-template

I would like to create a new component that inherits from an existing one.
I just want to add a few custom methods to the ts class file.
But I'm not sure how to reference the path to the parent html and scss template files -- I would like to just reuse them.

```
import { ParentComponent } from '@other/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: '../parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../parent.component.scss']
})
export class InheritedComponent extends ParentComponent {
  ....
```

Comment: I don't see any issue with your code

Comment: The code is in a project and the component extended is in the imported package.
Build (ng build myproj) doesn't work because it can't find those files locally.
I guess I need to make local copies of the parent component html and scss files, but that seems a waste.